# Inheritance method visibility concepts in java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class A {
public void method1{
   System.out.println("Method 1 called");
  }
public void method2{
   System.out.println("Method 2 called");
  }
}
class B extends A {
   B obj = new B();
   obj.method1();// should be present in scope
   obj.method2();// should not be accessible.Should not be present in scope.
} 
class C extends A {
   C obj = new C();
   obj.method2(); // should be present in scope.
   obj.method1(); // should not be accessible. Should not present in scope.
}
```

Description: Consider the above example in which A is a super class and classes B, C are sub classes.

Is their any appropriate procedure through which we can make implementations as below:

1. Subclass B  must be able to access method1() only but not method2().
2. Subclass C must be able to access method2() but not method1().

Thank you

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you  please elaborate?

Comment: Well why *would* two subclasses of the same superclass see different things? If they should inherit different things, they should inherit them from *different superclasses*. I suspect an http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Out of curiosity.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thank you, I know the straight forward implementation. This is just a corner case  in order to check if any possibilities exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is their any appropriate procedure through which we can make implementations as below:
>   Subclass B must be able to access method1() only but not method2().
>   Subclass C must be able to access method2() but not method1().

It will not be possible because if you want to prevent inheritance of a member, you set it as `private`.

However, once you set it to private, neither subclass B nor subclass C will be able to inherit that member.

Comment: Technically if you make something package-private, and declare one subclass in the same package and the other not, you could make the visibility different, but that still wouldn't achieve what the OP is talking about.